# Curl of Cross Product of Two Vectors

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

I want to prove the following identity

$$\text{curl } \left(\textbf{F}\times \textbf{G}\right) = \textbf{F}\text{ div}\textbf{ G}- \textbf{G}\text{ div}\textbf{ F}+ \left(\textbf{G}\cdot \nabla \right)\textbf{F}- \left(\textbf{F}\cdot \nabla \right)\textbf{G}$$

But I do not know how! Also, what does $\textbf{F}\cdot \nabla $ mean, isn't it the divergence of $\textbf{F}$!

Answer (score 51):

You only need two things to prove this.  First, the BAC-CAB rule:

$$A \times (B \times C) = B(A \cdot C) - C(A \cdot B)$$

And the product rule.  Let $\dot \nabla \times (\dot F \times G)$ mean "differentiate $F$ only; pretend $G$ is constant here".  So the product rule would read

$$\nabla \times (F \times G) = \dot \nabla \times (\dot F \times G) + \dot \nabla \times (F \times \dot G)$$

Now, apply the BAC-CAB rule.  I'll do this for just one term for brevity:

$$\dot \nabla \times (\dot F \times G) = \dot F (\dot \nabla \cdot G) - G(\dot \nabla \cdot \dot F)$$

Now, here's where the dots become important:  since $G$ is not differentiated in this whole equation, $\dot \nabla \cdot G$ is a directional derivative, conventionally written $G \cdot \nabla$.  Indeed, we have

$$\dot F(\dot \nabla \cdot G) = (G \cdot \nabla) F$$

On the other hand, the $G(\dot \nabla \cdot \dot F)$ term can just drop the dots to get something that looks like a divergence:

$$G (\dot \nabla \cdot \dot F) = G(\nabla \cdot F)$$

Carry out the same expansion for the $\dot \nabla \times (F \cdot \dot G)$ term, and you're done.

Comment: i dont get why should i use the product rule, why is BAC-CAB rule not enough. in the end its just a cross product, right?

Comment: Both $F$ and $G$ are being differentiated here.  You have to use the product rule at some point.  You do not have the option not to.  You could use the product rule second if you prefer, after the BAC-CAB rule, but you can't choose not to use the product rule here.  That would be like making the mistake $\frac{d}{dx} [f(x) g(x) ]= g(x) \frac{df}{dx}$.  It's...wrong.

Comment: i know what is product rule, but we are finding triple product

Comment: what you said, gives the right answer but not the satisfaction

Comment: It merely sounds to me that you're unfamiliar with vector calculus versions of the product rule, but they are no more exotic than the single-variable version and follow directly from that version (which can be proved by breaking into components, if you insist).  The overdot notation I used here is just a convenient way of not having to write out components while still invoking the product rule. When you differentiate a product in single-variable calculus, you use a product rule. When you differentiate a product of vectors, there is a vector extension of the product rule. Seems sensible to me.

Comment: i think, i should do some more study, your answer was help

Comment: I can't believe that $G \cdot \nabla$ is just the directional derivative.  I've been through multivariable calculus, real analysis, mathematical methods in physics, and have started learning the diff geometry of curves and surfaces on my own and the only time I ever used used that identity (other than just proving it via index notation) I had to break it into components because I didn't know what it meant.  Man... It seems like somebody should have told me something as simple as this before now.  Mind = Blown.

Comment: $(G\cdot \nabla )F$ is very simple to understand. think abt it,

Comment: Yeah, I realize that now -- I worked it out.  I just remember coming across that notation a couple of times and my professors just not ever explaining what it was -- so I just figured it was something advanced I hadn't gotten to, yet.  It was just very surprising to me that all it is is the directional derivative of $F$ in the direction $G$.  My professors definitely could have told me that the first time one of these identities came up in class.

Comment: @Muphrid: What happened to the dot over F in equation 4, above? I understand the removal of dots in the last equation but not in the one before...

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora The dots would be redundant on the right-hand side of that equation, once $G, \nabla, F$ are written in that order. This is a typical notation for directional derivatives in vector calculus at this level.

Comment: @Muphrid. I guess you mean when F, $\div$ and G are written in that order?

Comment: it makes perfect sense without dot annotations, if you look at nabla operator just as multivariate derivative

Answer (score 18):

Here is a simple proof using **index notation** and *BAC-CAB* identity.

$$\begin{align}
\nabla  \times \left( {{\bf{A}} \times {\bf{B}}} \right) &= {{\bf{e}}_i} \times {\partial _i}\left( {{A_j}{{\bf{e}}_j} \times {B_k}{{\bf{e}}_k}} \right)\\
&= {\partial _i}\left( {{A_j}{B_k}} \right){{\bf{e}}_i} \times \left( {{{\bf{e}}_j} \times {{\bf{e}}_k}} \right)\\
&= \left( {{\partial _i}{A_j}{B_k} + {A_j}{\partial _i}{B_k}} \right)\left( {\left( {{{\bf{e}}_i} \cdot {{\bf{e}}_k}} \right){{\bf{e}}_j} - \left( {{{\bf{e}}_i} \cdot {{\bf{e}}_j}} \right){{\bf{e}}_k}} \right)\\
&= \left( {{\partial _i}{A_j}{B_k} + {A_j}{\partial _i}{B_k}} \right)\left( {{\delta _{ik}}{{\bf{e}}_j} - {\delta _{ij}}{{\bf{e}}_k}} \right)\\
&= {\partial _i}{A_j}{B_i}{{\bf{e}}_j} - {\partial _i}{A_i}{B_k}{{\bf{e}}_k} + {A_j}{\partial _i}{B_i}{{\bf{e}}_j} - {A_i}{\partial _i}{B_k}{{\bf{e}}_k}\\
&= {\bf{B}} \cdot \nabla {\bf{A}} - \left( {\nabla  \cdot {\bf{A}}} \right){\bf{B}} + \left( {\nabla  \cdot {\bf{B}}} \right){\bf{A}} - {\bf{A}} \cdot \nabla {\bf{B}}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 14):

The divergence is $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F}$ whereas $(\mathbf{F}\cdot\nabla)$ is another way of writing the [directional derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) operator. In component notation we have

$$(\mathbf{F}\cdot\nabla) = \sum_{\alpha=1}^dF_\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\alpha}$$

which when applied to each component ($\beta$) of $\mathbf{G}$ gives

$$\left((\mathbf{F}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf G\right)_\beta = \sum_{\alpha=1}^dF_\alpha\frac{\partial G_\beta}{\partial x_\alpha} $$

which is the same as if we consider $\mathbf{F}\cdot(\nabla\otimes\mathbf{G})$ where $\nabla\otimes\mathbf{G}$ is

$$\left(\nabla\otimes\mathbf{G}\right)_{\alpha \beta}= \frac{\partial G_\beta}{\partial x_\alpha}$$

Comment: is there an easy way to prove the main problem i posted

Comment: I would start with one of the sides, write it in component notation and then use rearrangement, expansion, etc to get it into the form of the the other side. Though you will end up with lots of terms and it might take a while. If you want to know how to do that, perhaps post it as another question.

Answer (score -5):

It's easiest to see by writing it out in components:

[ ( ∇ ⋅ a ) b ]i = ( ∂x ax + ∂y ay + ∂z az )bi = ( ∂x ax )bi + ( ∂y ay )bi + ( ∂z az )bi

Whereas

[(∇⋅a)b]i=(∂x ax +∂y ay +∂z az)bi =(∂x ax)bi +(∂y ay)bi +(∂z az)bi

and clearly these are not the same. So while a ⋅ b = b ⋅ a a⋅b=b⋅a holds when a and b are really vectors, it is not necessarily true when one of them is a vector operator. This is one of the cases where the convenience of considering ∇ ∇ as a vector satisfying all the rules for vectors does not apply.