# Verify the following relationship: $\nabla \cdot (a \times b) = b \cdot \nabla \times a - a \cdot \nabla \times b $

Tags: vector-analysis

Verify the vector identity:

$\nabla \cdot (a  \times b) = b \cdot \nabla \times a - a \cdot \nabla \times b $

Given that:

$a = (R_a, S_a, T_a)$, $b = (R_b, S_b, T_b)$ and $\nabla = (\frac{\partial} {\partial x},\frac{\partial} {\partial y},\frac{\partial} {\partial z} )$.

Where $R_i, S_i, T_i$ have continuous partial derivatives.

I attempted it on paper but cannot get it to work. Can anyone show me how this is done?

**My working:**

LHS:

$\nabla \cdot (a  \times b) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(S_a T_b - S_b T_a) + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(T_a R_b - R_a T_b) + \frac{\partial}{\partial z}(R_a S_b - R_b S_a)  $

RHS:

$\nabla \times a = (\frac{\partial}{\partial y} T_a - \frac{\partial}{\partial z} S_a)\hat i - (\frac{\partial}{\partial x} T_a - \frac{\partial}{\partial z} R_a)\hat j + (\frac{\partial}{\partial x} S_a - \frac{\partial}{\partial y} R_a)\hat k$

$b \cdot (\nabla \times a) = R_b(\frac{\partial}{\partial y} T_a - \frac{\partial}{\partial z} S_a) - S_b(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} T_a - \frac{\partial}{\partial z} R_a) + T_b(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} S_a - \frac{\partial}{\partial y} R_a)$

Now I computed the other part of the RHS as well however I can't see how I would be able to maninipulate it into the LHS.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Just compute it component-wise.  It would be best if you were to show your work, so that we can identify your error.

Comment: Note that the chain rule derivation cannot work for curl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Leibniz rule in the firts term:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(S_aT_b - S_bT_a) = T_b\frac{\partial S_a}{\partial x} + S_a\frac{\partial T_b}{\partial x} - T_a\frac{\partial S_b}{\partial x} - S_b \frac{\partial Ta}{\partial x}.
$$

Expanding the other two you should get the desired equality.

Another approach can be using [index notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507312/proving-product-rule-identity-using-index-notation/2507388#2507388).

Answer (score 0):

There's a much more convenient derivation using the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) and the properties of the [mixed product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Scalar_triple_product). In particular it holds that cyclic shift doesn't change the result of a mixed product:
$$
  a \cdot (b \times c) = b \cdot (c \times a) = c \cdot (a \times b) \: .
$$
Now applying the chain rule to the expression in question, we get:
$$
  \nabla \cdot (a \times b) = \nabla_a \cdot (a \times b) + \nabla_b \cdot (a \times b) \: ,
$$
where $\nabla_a$ takes a derivative of $a$ and sees $b$ as a constant, and $\nabla_b$ vice versa. (This works exactly the same as the dot notation in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/849076/142487).) Now, shifting the factors in the first term *to the right* and the factors in the second term *to the left*, we get:
$$
  \nabla \cdot (a \times b) = b \cdot (\nabla_a \times a) + a \cdot (b \times \nabla_b) \: .
$$
Finally, we change the order of multiplication in the second cross product. Since $a\times b = -b \times a$, we get:
$$
  \nabla \cdot (a \times b) = b \cdot (\nabla_a \times a) - a \cdot (\nabla_b \times b) \: .
$$
Since both nablas now only act on the factor that is directly to the right, we can drop the subscript and arive at the equation in question.