# double curl and vector laplacian

Tags: vector-analysis

I am currently reading "Classical Electrodynamics" by Jackson and I couldn't reproduce a calculation made there.

I got $$\vec{A} = - ik \frac{e^{ikr}}{r} \vec{d}$$ and I want to calculate the following two things $$\vec{B} = \nabla \times \vec{A} \\
\vec{E} = \frac{i}{k} \nabla \times \left( \nabla \times \vec{A} \right)$$
Calculating $\vec{B}$ was pretty easy and straightforward by using $\nabla \times \left( f(r)\vec{d} \right) = f'(r) \frac{\vec{r}}{r} \times \vec{d}$ for a constant $\vec{d}$.
I get $$\vec{B} = e^{ikr} \left( \frac{k^2}{r^2} + \frac{ik}{r^3} \right) \vec{r} \times \vec{d}$$
which is identical to the calculation in the book.

When I   calculate $\vec{E}$ I don't get the book's solution, which is $$\vec{E} = k^2 \left(\vec{n} \times \vec{d} \right) \times \vec{n} \frac{e^{ikr}}{r} + \left[ 3 \vec{n} \left( \vec{n} \cdot \vec{d} \right) - \vec{d} \right] \left[ \frac{1}{r^3} -
 \frac{ik}{r^2} \right] e^{ikr} $$

I tried using the identity $$\nabla \times \left( \nabla \times \vec{A} \right) = \nabla \left( \nabla \cdot \vec{A} \right) - \Delta \vec{A},$$ but I couldn't find an elegant way of calculating $\Delta \vec{A}$. 
I think it should be possible by using the vector laplacian as described here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorLaplacian.html and just calculating it but isn't there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could use [this identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836041/curl-of-cross-product-of-two-vectors)  for $F= e^{ikr} ( k^2/r^2 + ik/r^3) \vec r$ and $G=\vec d$, then all the derivative falling on $G$ vanish.

Comment: I tried calculating it using that identity and my solution is $\vec{E} = e^{ikr} \left( \frac{2}{r^3} - \frac{2ik}{r^2} \right) \vec{d}$. I couldn't get the book's solution into the shape of my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The basic identity for the Laplacian acting on purely radial functions is 
$$
\Delta f(r)= \frac{1}{r} \partial_r^2~ (rf(r)),
$$
on top of the action of the gradient on such, which you know, above.

Thus,
$$
\vec{E}=\frac{i}{k}   \nabla \times \left( \nabla \times \vec{A} \right) =\frac{i}{k} \nabla \left( \nabla \cdot \vec{A} \right) - \frac{i}{k}\Delta \vec{A},  
$$
and
$$
\frac{i}{k}\Delta \vec{A} =\frac{1}{r}\vec{d} ~\partial_r^2 e^{ikr}= \frac{-k^2}{r}\vec{d}  ~ e^{ikr}.
$$

Furthermore, 
$$
\frac{i}{k}\nabla \cdot \vec{A}=\vec{d}\cdot \nabla ~\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}= \vec{d}\cdot \vec{r} ~ e^{ikr}\left (\frac{ik}{r^2}-\frac{1}{r^3}\right ),
$$
so that 
$$
\frac{i}{k}\nabla (\nabla \cdot \vec{A})= \vec{d}~e^{ikr}\left (\frac{ik}{r^2}-\frac{1}{r^3}\right )+\hat{r} (\hat{r}\cdot\vec{d}) r\partial_r~ e^{ikr}\left (\frac{ik}{r^2}-\frac{1}{r^3}\right )\\ 
=  \vec{d}~e^{ikr}\left (\frac{ik}{r^2}-\frac{1}{r^3}\right )+\hat{r} (\hat{r}\cdot\vec{d})  ~ \frac{e^{ikr}}{r}\left (-k^2 -\frac{3ik}{r}+\frac{3}{r^2}\right ).
$$

Consequently,
$$
\vec{E}=  \vec{d}~\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}\left (\frac{ik}{r}-\frac{1}{r^2} +k^2\right )+\hat{r} (\hat{r}\cdot\vec{d})  ~ \frac{e^{ikr}}{r}\left (-k^2 -\frac{3ik}{r}+\frac{3}{r^2}\right )\\
=\frac{e^{ikr}}{r} \left ( \vec{d}~\left (\frac{ik}{r}-\frac{1}{r^2} +k^2\right )+\hat{r} (\hat{r}\cdot\vec{d})  ~  \left (-k^2 -\frac{3ik}{r}+\frac{3}{r^2}\right )\right  ) 
.
$$

- Needless to say, this is the very expression you are targetting, once you evaluate its double cross product, $ \frac{e^{ikr}}{r}\left ( k^2 (\vec{d} -\hat{r} ~\hat{r}\cdot \vec{d} ) + ( 3 \hat{r} ~ \hat{r} \cdot \vec{d}   - \vec{d}) \left[ \frac{1}{r^2} -
   \frac{ik}{r} \right] \right )$ , and reduce it to a canonical form such as the one found.